# Issue with no of days while adding date in current datetime

Tags: php, datetime

I am currently working on a package subscription manager where I have to calculate the expiry date by adding the duration in current date.

Below is my code that does it:

```
function generateExpiryDate($start_date, $package_duration)
{
    $expires = strtotime(date($start_date)." + $package_duration");
    return date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $expires);
}

$current_date = "2012-10-23 19:12:19";
$duration = "6 Months";
$expiry_date = generateExpiryDate($current_date, $duration);
```

When I echo $current_date and $expiry_date, it shows
2012-10-23 19:41:14
2013-04-23 19:41:14

Notice it is just adding no of months in the month and doesnt take care of no of days in month like 31 days, 28 days, 29 days or 30 days.
I want it to take those things into account.

Please help me to get it right.

Comment: 10.23.2012 + 6 months *is* 4.23.2013 -- what did you want it to be?

Comment: $date = strtotime(date("Y-m-d", strtotime($date)) . " +6 month"); similar to this

Comment: yes i realized that its working fine after i have gone through the testing thoroughly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$date = date($current_date);// current date
$expiry_date =strtotime(date("Y-m-d", strtotime($date)) . " +6 month");
```